# how to configure Spring integration FTP for dynamic inbound?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ftp, spring-integration

I am new to spring ftp integration. I want to download files from FTP server using dynamic parameters like host, username, password etc from database. I understand how to downloaded files using static parameters from properties file. I have succeeded in uploading files(**ftp outbound**) using *dynamic parameters* by referring to [Dynamic FTP Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) example. 
Please, help me configuring "inbound dynamic ftp" .

I have successfully implemented this but I am facing few new issue with this solution.

Scenario: Say the ftp server host name is "ftp.foo.in" and have a folder structure like

```
/ (root)  
  |- countries  
    |- states  
      |- cities
```

Problems: 
 1) On accessing sub folders, it throws **Unknownhostexception**. For Example, if I try to       connect with host name="ftp.foo.in/countries/states", then it throws exception as follows:

```
      ERROR: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:139)
        at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.FTPInboundRecursiveFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.FTPInboundRecursiveFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:67)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.foo.in/countries/states
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1215)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1063)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1013)
        at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.createClient(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:152)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:136)
        ... 22 more
```

Where as if I try to access sub folders by using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FtpClient's changeWorkingDirectory(), it successfully executes.

2) If I pass credentials like username/password wrong, then it will display the stack trace **infinitely**. I want that spring integration module, should try to resolve with wrong credentials once and print stack trace once only . 
I debugged it to inner code and found cause. Actually, when spring integration module fail to establish condition  , it prints stack trace and it internally reschedule the attempt to connect with same credentials(in this case wrong credentials) continuously. Have I missed out any configuration regarding this?

Comment: Maybe naivly replace `outbound` with `inbound` in the sample? Just wondering why does it have to be dynamic?

Comment: @M.Deinum : By replacing outbound with inbound,I will get MeesageChannel reference whereas to I want PollableChannel so that on calling receive(), data can be downloaded. The configuration parameters(like host,username,password) value will come from database. So, I want to configure dynamically, not using properties file.

Comment: And why is it different, what does it matter where the properties come from? You can simply create a `FactoryBean` which loads the properties from a database, passes this to the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` and have all the spring goodies. Hence my question why does it have to be dynamic? Do you change properties at runtime, do you have multiple clients (multi-tenancy) or is it just the fact that the properties come from a different location?

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes, I have multiple clients detail stored in database table. At runtime, one specific client configuration will be read from database and connection will be established on the fly.

Comment: BTW a `PollableChannel` is a `MessageChannel`. However you should be able to put a gateway or bridge with a pollable channel in-front of the inboud-gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this spring forum thread [Dynamic Inbound Channel Adapter creation](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/119081-dynamic-inbound-channel-adapter-creation) and follow its links (specifically [this one](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/117523-starting-multiple-consumers?p=589517#post589517)).

Essentially, you make the main context the parent of the (s)ftp context so the inbound adapter can reference the channel.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have successfully used resolver for dynamic behaviour.

Comment: I am facing a new issue with this solution.