# Transfer files on different servers (sftp) using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

I have a requirement to build an application in SI which reads an input directory which may consist 1000s of file and copy them to remote servers, say 10 servers where a processor instance will pick them up for processing.The movement of file should be on round-robin fashion so that there is not additional burden on any server while processing them. To elaborate a little more - lets say we have 10 files in input directory then application should copy 
file 1 on server1,
file2 on server2 
.
.
.
....
file 10 on server 10.

Sequence doesn't matter what matters is that every server should have equal load.I am fairly new to Spring Integration but I found a sample to do sftp of file using SI

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp

but i am not sure how can I configure it for multiple servers and to have an algo to move files in round-robin fashion.

I will appreciate any tips or suggestion .

I am able to do sftp using below config.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="ReaderChannel"
    directory="file:${input.file.dir}" filename-pattern="*.*"
    prevent-duplicates="true" ignore-hidden="true" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="1" task-executor="myTaskExecutor" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-task:executor id="myTaskExecutor"  pool-size="${file.concurrentFilesNum}" queue-capacity="0"   rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="ReaderChannel"
    charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="${output.file.dir}" auto-startup="true">
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<beans:bean id="sftpSessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <beans:property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
    <beans:property name="privateKey" value="${sftp.private.keyfile}" />
    <beans:property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sftp.private.passphrase}" />
    <beans:property name="port" value="${sftp.serverPort}" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
    <beans:property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `round-robin` is hidden in the `DirectChannel` with `UnicastingDispatcher` on the `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy`.

So, when you have several subscriber to the same `DirectChannel`, the message will be dispatched to them in the `round-robin`.

What you need for your use-case is just configure 10 `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` for each your remote server. And use the same simple `<channel>` definition for their `channel` attribute.

The `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` should always send its message to that shared channel with default `round-robin` strategy.

Comment: @ Artem Bilan - Thanks for suggetion. I read about Direct Channel and it seems what you said is true                                                                                 [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-directchannel)                         The only problem with this approach is that i need to know the number of servers beforehand otherwise everytime I remove or add new server from the list I would need to change the code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure in your concern. The `DirectChannel` (and its `UnicastingDispatcher`) does the automatic adjustment according to the `subscribe/unsubscribe` functions on it. Would you mind to share some "guilty code" on the matter in your question?

Comment: I have added my config which i am using for sftp . .

Comment: OK. Your point is to add servers at runtime. That is fully different story and you didn't reflect that in your question. So, you need something like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370127/how-to-configure-spring-integration-ftp-for-dynamic-inbound

Comment: This example served the purpose. Thanks Artem

Comment: You got it brother  :)  ! ! !